HTTP 413 error uploading large file on apache
Using django-filer admin file manager to upload 2GB large file. On the same windows machine, works OK in vscode development environment, but return http 413 on apache ssl enabled http server. And works fine with small size file uploading. Following are the apache conf file setting.
...
Timeout 600
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
<ifModule mod_reqtimeout.c>
RequestReadTimeout header=0,MinRate=500 body=0,MinRate=500
</ifModule>

KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 600
KeepAliveTimeout 5
... 

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  <Location />
    SSLRenegBufferSize 2048600000
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>  

Expecting uploading 2GB also success in apache http server.

2GB can be 2_147_483_648 = 210241024*1024

Tried, same thing. Tried 1.5GB file upload also failed. Thanks.

if you could test smaller files then you could find size which works - and maybe it helps to find settings in different place which uses this size. Maybe it depends on some global settings.

in this article How To Increase File Upload Size In Apache - Ubiq BI they use LimitRequestBody. In some other article (about PHP in Apache) someone suggests settings in PHP - so maybe Django has also own settings for upload size limit.

apache 2.2 - Can't increase max POST size in Apache2 - Server Fault

Yeah, I didn't set LimitRequestBody in conf file. So, it's default is 0, meaning unlimited. I can upload up to 1GB, no more than 1,073,741,824 bytes. Maybe it's limit of my server. I use min PC as server. Thank you furas.
